# Why do subspaces of the space of Global holomorphic differentials of a function field correspond to its subfields

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, computational-number-theory

I'm asking this question as a follow up to the [Felipe Voloch](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2290/felipe-voloch)'s answer to this question:

[Subfields of a function field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56693/subfields-of-a-function-field)

which you can read it here:

[Subfields of a function field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56693/subfields-of-a-function-field/56774#56774)

(I just didn't have much faith in attracting attention to an already-answered question, so I started a new one).

So, my question is that I have no idea why the mentioned algorithm works? Basically how one proves that every subfield of $F$ corresponds to a subspace of the space of Global homomorphic differentials of $F$. Unfortunately, the "(proof left to the reader)", didn't worked out for me.

I would be more than grateful, if you suggest me a reference that helps me to tackles the math behind the algorithm.

Comment: Not every subspace correspond to a (proper) subfield. But you get a subspace from a subfield by looking at the pullbacks of the holomorphic differentials of the subfield. I was just using the fact that, for a non-hyperelliptic curve, the canonical morphism is an embedding. This is all in Hartshorne.